# How to fix "Multiple instances of Vue detected!" with parcel.js and bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, parceljs

How do I solve the warning `multiple instances of vue detected!` please?

My index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/cssreset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>

<body>  
    <div class='app' id='app'>
    </div>
    <script src="code/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js file:

```
import Vue from '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

const app = new Vue
({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
})
```

and my package.json file has this (which doesn't seem to make a difference):

```
  "alias": {
    "vue" : "./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  },
```

Comment: Why do you need '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common' ?  The alias presumes that `vue` import is used, still depends on the setup but isn't supposed to affect relative import any way.

Comment: At first I just had `import Vue from 'vue'` but that gave me this error: `[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`

Comment: It's supposed to be affected by `alias` this way. Is it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean. What is "it"?  Affected by alias how?  It looks like alias isn't being used, because I can change the path I give in the value of alias for vue to gibberish and everything still builds fine.

Comment: `vue` alias is supposed to affect how  `vue` import works. I'd expect it to do what you want when you import it like `import Vue from 'vue'` and not `import Vue from '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common'`. If builds fine when you use gibberish alias with `import Vue from 'vue'` then you have a problem somewhere in the config, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem then, it's likely specific to your Parcel setup.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm not sure what else to add to my question. I only have those 3 files so far. Oh, and my build command: `node ./node_modules/.bin/parcel src/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

The alias field in the package.json needs to change to `"vue": "/../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js"`. Parcel will not complain if your alias field is wrong when compiling so you have to be very careful about specifying the correct path yourself, depending on your build command's root folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions ( maybe this will save time for someone).

1: add this line in the webpack config file :

```js
let whiteListedModules = ['vue', 'bootstrap-vue']
```

2: Change the import line to :

```js
Vue.use(require('bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.common.min'));
```

[source](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3351)